# Как использовать Github OAuth API в Django?

Tags: github, django

с отправкой GET запроса нет проблем. Возвращаю ответ urlopen через HttpResponse. Появляется форма входа. Но после нее меня редиректит почему то на http://localhost:8000/session. Как обработать входящий этот запрос и отправить его через POST на https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?